# How to resolve dependency in integration test Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, integration-testing

I don't have much experience with integration tests but I will try to explain what I am trying to do.

I have created an endpoint which reads data from database.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductService _productService;

    public ProductController (IProductService productService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
        }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
       {
          return _productService.GetAllProducts();
       }
}

public class ProductService: IProductService
{
    private IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public ProductService(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            _productRepository = productRepository;
        }

    public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return _productRepository.GetProducts();
        }
 }

public class ProductRepository: IProductRepository
{
   public List<Product> GetProducts()
       {
            //database call to get products;
       }
}
```

I have resolved dependencies for repository and other services using SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver.

Now I have created an unit test project where I have mocked the response from service.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ProductControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IProductService> _productService;

    private ProductController _productController;


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _productService = new Mock<IProductService>();

        _productController= new ProductController(_productService.Object);
    }

}
```

this works fine. I can return the Mock data.

for integration tests I created a separate project in which I want to hit the repository and get the real data back, but how can I resolve the dependencies for IProductService in integration test so that I will hit the repository and I can get the real data from database back. How can use dependency injection in the integration test to resolve dependencies.

```
public class ProductControllerIntegrationTests
{
    private ProductService _productService;

    private ProductController _productController;


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
       {
             // how to resolve the dependency for _productService
             _productController= new ProductController(_productService);
        }
 }
```

Comment: You can isolate the code that configures dependencies into its own class or classes that you call from startup. If that class needs runtime values like connection strings, etc. from configuration, write the class so that you must pass those values to it. Then, in your integration tests, use the exact same classes to register your dependencies, and resolve the class you want to test from the container. That way you ensure that the class you're testing is created exactly the same way as it would be in production.

Comment: If you include the code that registers your dependencies I can provide an example. It might not be NUnit-specific, but it will be close enough for you to get the idea.

Comment: right.  You need to add an IOC container to your Integration Tests.  Usually, in unit tests, this isn't done.

Comment: Thanks Scott and TheMikeInNYC. I install IOC conatiner in integration tests project. Its working perfectly.